# what is mongoose connection validity time?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, connection-string, connection-pooling

I have custom circuit breaker logic for 3rd party services. I checked mongoose connection status like below,

```
mongoose.connection.on("connected", function() {
    console.log("Mongoose connected");
});
mongoose.connection.on("disconnected", function() {
    console.log("Mongoose disconnected");
});
```

while running on server logs like below,

```
Mongoose disconnected //Happened 12.30PM
// after sometime 
Mongoose connected //Happened 12.35PM
Mongoose disconnected //Happened 12.35PM
Mongoose connected //Happened 12.35PM
```

My connection string,

```
mongoose.connect(URL, {
    keepAlive: true,
    keepAliveInitialDelay: 300000,
    socketTimeoutMS: 300000,
    poolSize: 10,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useCreateIndex: true
})
```

1. I dont know while connect why system act like above in same second of time interval ?
2. Why mongo connection goes to disconneted mode even i apply "keepAlive" ?
3. Is there any validity for mongoose connection alive status?

Comment: poolSize: 300000 ? I wonder who can swim that much =)

Comment: Opps I copy pasting same value :( 
poolSize: 10